# Div heights sum 100%, extending past container div

Tags: css

I'm making an achievement list userscript for an online browser game and am confused by my menus behavior. I have my main background `div`, and within there are 3 `divs`: a header with height 10%, the body with height 80%, and my footer with height 10%. Since I don't have a margin on any of them I'd expect the bottom of the footer to reach the bottom of the background, but for some reason it's being moved downwards.

Here's some picture using chrome dev tools:

[image: footer] [image: body]

As seen, the footer div's top isn't aligned with the body div's bottom. Does anyone know why this might be happening? I'm going to add a picture of my CSS as seen through chrome, but if you want my actual code let me know. I have 3 div's who's height add up to 100% but they extend further down than the bottom of their container.

[image: css]

Edit: here's my actual code:

```
function showMenu(){                                            // Show menu when user presses home button
    var menu = document.createElement('div');
    $(menu).css({
        'height':'500px',
        'width':'400px',
        'background-color':'#00ACE9',
        'position':'absolute',
        'top':'10em',
        'left':'50%',
        'border-radius':'5%',
        'border':'3px solid black',
        'transform':'translate(-50%, 0)',
        'zIndex':'30'
    }).attr('id', 'AchieveMenu');
    var footer = document.createElement('div');
    $(footer).css({
        'margin-top':'0',
        'padding-top':'0',
        'width':'100%',
        'height':'5%',
        'position':'relative'
    });
    var footerText = document.createElement('p');
    $(footerText).text('Press on achievement to see current status').appendTo(footer).css({
        'text-align':'center',
    });
    var heading = document.createElement('h1');
    $(heading).text('Achievements').css({
        'position':'relative',
        'color':'#893667',
        'padding-top':'5px',
        'padding-bottom':'5px',
        'left':'60px',
        'display':'inline'
    });
    var seperator = document.createElement('div');    // This is header
    $(seperator).css({                  
        'width':'100%',
        'height':'10%',
        'position':'relative',
        'border-bottom':'2px solid black'
    });
    var exit = document.createElement('button');                // Hides menu button
    $(exit).html('X').click(hideMenu).css({
        'border':'solid 3px black',
        'float':'right',
        'border-radius':'100%',
        'background-color':'#c2c2d6'
    });
    var awardsDiv = document.createElement('div');              // Holds achievement table
    $(awardsDiv).css({
        'position':'relative',
        'width':'100%',
        'height':'80%',
        'overflow':'scroll',
        'margin-left':'auto',
        'margin-right':'auto',
        'border-bottom':'2px solid black'
    });
    var awards = document.createElement('table');               // Table for achievements
    var awardString = getAwards();                              // Get html for achievements table
    $(awards).css({
        'position':'relative',
        'width':'100%',
        'height':'100%',
        'border-spacing':'collapse'
    }).html(awardString);
    $(awards).find('td').css({
        'padding-top':'5px',
        'padding-left':'10px',
        'font':'15pt monospace',
        'color':'black'
    });
    $(awards).each(function(){$(this).find('tr:odd').css('background-color','#99ccff')});
    $(awards).each(function(){$(this).find('tr:even').css('background-color','#cce6ff')});
    $(awardsDiv).append(awards);
    $(seperator).append(heading, exit);
    $(menu).append(seperator, awardsDiv, footer);
    $('body').append(menu);
```

Comment: Please post the related code. remove `body` and `html` padding and margin too.

Comment: I added my code, it's all added dynamically using jQuery.

Comment: [not related] It seems you are using jquery too much unnecessarily.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate on that. I'm a beginner.

Comment: To apply styles, you should use css. Add classes to your dynamic elements but not each style.

Comment: Hmm I'm not fully understanding.

Comment: Keep the css styles in css files. don't use jquery to add css styles.

Comment: This is a userscript that people add as an extension, I can't just add a CSS file

Comment: Instead using `height: 10%` use `eight: 10vh`